# How to use the slice command to visualize one image into two intersecting planes?

Tags: matlab

I need to visualize one image in two intersecting planes. The attached picture shows an example of what I want to do. However, it uses an equation:
`(V = X.*exp(-X.^2-Y.^2-Z.^2);)` , while I want to insert my image instead.

```matlab
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(-2:.2:2);
V = X.*exp(-X.^2-Y.^2-Z.^2);
xslice = 0;   
yslice = [];
zslice = 0;
slice(X,Y,Z,V,xslice,yslice,zslice)
```

Comment: where is the attached picture?

Comment: what do you mean by 'insert .. image'? the example provided is a 3D potential or field amplitude that is being sliced with 2 perpedicular planes. Do you mean you need to replace the V=X.*exp.. expression with another expression? or what you are really after is to print a 2D custom image on one of the slicing planes?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The code draws two squares in two perpendicular planes. I want to replace the squares with my image. I want to attach a picture showing exactly what I want but I do not see how to do it. If you want I can send it to you via your email. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

command `warp` has an example showing how to print an custom impage on an arbitrary surface, have a look [**here**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/warp.html)

This is the example :

**1.-** Load the custom image

```
[I,map] = imread('custom_image.tif');
```

These are all the image formats that can be loaded with `imread`

.bmp
.jpeg
.png
.cur
.ppm
.gif
.pbm
.ras
.hdf4
.pcx
.tiff
.ico
.pgm
.xwd

`imread` further details available [**here**](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html?searchHighlight=imread&s_tid=srchtitle_imread_1#mw_abb56802-ede7-4bfd-a64e-0743144c1db9)

**2.-** Define the surface

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-100:100,-80:80);
Z = -(X.^2 + Y.^2);
```

**3.- Print any image on any surface generated with** `warp`

```
figure
warp(X,Y,Z,I,map);
```

**4.- Print any image on any surface generated with** `surf`

```
I2=imread('forest2.jpg');
figure
imshow(I2)
```

[image]

```
I3r=imresize(I2(:,:,1),size(X));
I3g=imresize(I2(:,:,2),size(X));
I3b=imresize(I2(:,:,3),size(X));

I3=zeros([size(X) 3]);
I3(:,:,1)=I3r;I3(:,:,2)=I3g;I3(:,:,3)=I3b;
I3=uint8(I3);

I3map=[I3r(:) I3g(:) I3b(:)];

figure
hs=surf(X,Y,Z)
hs.EdgeColor='none'
hs.CData=I3
```

[image]

**5.-** How to define planes in MATLAB

Read my answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73718591/how-can-i-plot-a-plane-in-matlab-that-is-perpendicular-to-a-known-line-and-passe/73720721#73720721) to a question how to define planes. You will learn :

- how to define the plane **containing all 3 points**
- how to define planes **including any of 2 of the 3 input points**
- how to define the **perpendicular** plane **including 2 of the 3 input points**, and
- how to define **any** of the possible **perpendicular** planes **including 1 of the input points**

Comment: Thank you, Jhon. I really appreciate your help. The problem warp requires the DSP or image processing toolboxes which I do not have. Is there a way to go around? Thank you

Comment: I have added a way to print any image on any surface generated with command surf. One has to cast type uint8 to the image so that the range [0 255] is correctly accepted as colour range. You also use colormaps, a 2D colormap to the handle of surf, instead of RGB.